# Show View rotated at a specific angle and get view back when touched?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics, uiviewanimationtransition

I am creating a card game. I want to show cards rotated at bottom of screen along with if i touch on a card it slides a little upward and on second touch goes back to original position. I have done a simple arrangement also I am able to move card upwards and downwards but I am unable to get exact card for the touched position also I am only able to move card as per touchPoints y coordinate only. See screenShots below for better understanding.

1st screenshot is of arranged cards

[image]

2nd screenshot is of card moved upside

[image]

I just cards to be little tilted upward in the same angle in which they are. Also when i touch on second last card i got last card.

Comment: [This article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html) may be helpful for rotating the view using transforms.